# use Node.js to send a json request from client to the server

Tags: javascript, html, url, grails, client-server

i have a grails project works as a server. it receives a request from another javascript project. this request is json request.

**problem:**
server doesn't receive any request
i try to use node.js, how can i use it?

**Note:**
in the url mapping of the grails server project i declare this url and to access specific action in specific controller

thanks

Comment: What is the URL of the page where that code exists?

Comment: it is a local file.html in my pc (file:///home/danny/workspace/test.html)

Comment: Well that's your problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers will not allow you to issue ajax requests to a URL in a different domain. If that client code you posted is, as you say in a comment, in a "file:" URL on your machine, then the browser will not allow access to those "http://localhost" URLs via XMLHttpRequest (the innards of "$.ajax()").  It's called the "same origin policy."

If you could serve up your test page from a "http://localhost:8058" URL, then you'd be able to talk to the server.

Comment: how can i send a json request without ajax, if there is any another method please post it here

Comment: @danny-london: if you want to send a cross domain request, you can't do that from a web browser. If you want to this in JavaScript, use [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). But many other programming languages will also allow you to create JSON calls: Perl, PHP, Python...

Comment: If you need GET cross-domain request, you have to use JSONP request type. For POST there is two options: configure CORS (there is problems with some browser), or use EasyXDM library

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a file `jquery-1.6.2.js` in the same directory as the `.html` file.

Comment: jquery-1.6.2.js is in the same directory of .html file. any another idea

Comment: In that case, `$` should be known. But I see you removed those comments already.

Comment: yes i solve this error, $ is known now, the problem now is that server doesn't receive any request from client